# Magento2: Add pricing logic layer at the end

Tags: magento2, price, programmatically, layer

Before moving to Magento, I had a princing logic inside a table that involved (customer, customer group, item, item group, etc)

There are some native features that I will take advantage of such as tier prices and some more.

But in the end I will have to add some custom funcionalities about princing.
I was thinking about adding a custom layer at the end of calculating prices.
What I mean is, Magento calculates prices by layers, aproximately:

Regular price > Tier price > Special Price

**I would want to add my layer at the end.**

For testing I only wanted to add this layer and set the price to 5€ for example. Just for know that is working. **When I have this, for me it will be the solution**

The documentation is not helping so much: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/architecture/behavior/pricing.html

What I've done:

- Created my custom module.
- Added my logic pricing class, based on:

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/SpecialPrice.php`

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/SpecialPriceInterface.php`

```
namespace Gsp\SpecialPrices\Pricing\Price;

/**
 * Custom price interface
 */
interface CustomPriceInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns custom price
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getCustomPrice();

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isPercentageDiscount();
}
```

```
namespace Gsp\SpecialPrices\Pricing\Price;

class CustomPrice extends AbstractPrice implements CustomPriceInterface, BasePriceProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Price type special
     */
    const PRICE_CODE = 'custom_price';

    /**
     * @return bool|float
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    /**
     * Returns special price
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getCustomPrice()
    {
        return 9;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isPercentageDiscount()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Don't worry about the 5 or 9, I don't know what the heck am I doing. lul.
I only want to set the prices the amount I want.

- di.xml, adding my custom price:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\Pool" type="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular_price" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice</item>
                <item name="final_price" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice</item>
                <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice</item>
                <item name="special_price" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\SpecialPrice</item>
                <item name="base_price" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\BasePrice</item>
                <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\CustomOptionPrice
                </item>
                <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\ConfiguredPrice</item>
                <item name="custom_price" xsi:type="string">Gsp\SpecialPrices\Pricing\Price\CustomPrice</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Now the website is broken when I go to a product list or product view. It breaks exactly when it has to render the price. So I guess is working what I did but I'm missing something.

The log is showing that error:

```
main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_56f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

But I see this error is also displayed when I disable my module.
I have porto theme, and there isn't any layout named `catalog_product_prices.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still with this, but I think the solution is overriding the modules `catalogRule` and `salesRule`.

With this functionalities you would do all price changes you want, with rules.

Answer (score 0):

This Code Didn't Work And Where to use this code in Magento Custom Extention or Custom Created Code in special price